# зачем тут регулярное выражение?

Tags: python, django, регулярные-выражения

Есть вот такой код:

```
self.room_name = ...
self.room_group_name = 'chat_%s' % self.room_name
```

Зачем тут (выше) применять регулярное выражение, если можно просто написать так:

```
self.room_group_name = 'chat_' + self.room_name
```

Comment: а где там регулярное выражение?

Comment: %s - Строка (как обычно воспринимается пользователем).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
self.room_group_name = 'chat_%s' % self.room_name
```

Это не регулярное выражение, это шаблон форматирования. Удобство шаблонов начинается когда их становится много в строке. Строка с тучей конкатенаций воспринимается не так хорошо. Но вообще в современном питоне есть `f-строки`, они удобнее и понятнее:

```
self.room_group_name = f'chat_{self.room_name}'
```